# How to Store data using 'INTO' Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

I want to store the value of this query inside a Stored Procedure:

`select * from myname;`

using

`select * into mydata from myname`

but an error "mydata" is not a known variable occurs. Is there a way to store those results into a variable in postgre?

Comment: it's an sql inside a stored procedure.

Comment: Then you need to show us the *full* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to do this in the context of a PL/PgSQL function, then you have to declare the variable first.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foobar() RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    mydata RECORD;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO mydata FROM mytable;
    -- now do something with mydata
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

See:

- [Instructions for declaring row types & record types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-ROWTYPES)
- [Executing queries with one row result](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Comment: thank you...but i cant use mydata for a query like this one : ```select * from mydata```, i've got the error ```relation "mydata" does not exist```. Can ou help me in this matter?

Comment: You will need to explain better what you are trying to do. Are you trying to select from the variable? Or select from a table named by the variable?

Comment: Im trying to select from the variable.

Comment: Afaik you cannot select from a variable. Maybe you had better open a new question describing what you are trying to achieve at a higher level

Comment: thanks @harmic im a beginner when it comes to stored procedure.